# Navigation text overlapping in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Im using the whiteboard theme for wordpress.

My navigation is aligned to the right hand side of my header, however the navigation text is overlapping, the two inks in the navigation overlap each other on the header. any idea why?

```
#nav-primary {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
    #nav-primary ul,
    #nav-primary li {
        list-style: none;
    }
        #nav-primary a {
                position: absolute;
                right: 0;
                padding: 10px;
                width: auto;
                /*bottom: auto;*/

        }
```

Comment: Really hard to say much except everything in `#nav-primary a` except `padding: 10px;` would most likely be unnecessary. If you could provide an example page, that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using z-index:99; or create a relative div id if you are using position absolute.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `position: absolute` is doing you no favours here. Try removing this.

You also might be inheriting undesirable styles from your basic list style, but without seeing the whole CSS file we won't be able to determine that.